# how to run function insert or update on conflict on a table for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers, insert

I want to insert and update one table from another using the on conflict do update-feature.

I have tried to execute the function and none of them work.

> create or replace FUNCTION ecisdrdm.pr_mig_stg_application_cdim (v_Ret
>   OUT bigint )  as $$ declare 
>           v_ErrorCode             bigint;
>           v_ErrorMsg              varchar(512);
>           v_Module                varchar(32) = 'pr_mig_stg_application_cdim';
>
> begin
>
> ---
>
> ### -- MERGING: STG_APPLICATION_CDIM into APPLICATION_CDIM
>
> INSERT INTO application_cdim AS prod (prod.application_id,
>   prod.receipt_number,prod.init_frm_id, prod.frm_typ_id,
>     prod.sbmtd_dt_id, prod.crtd_user_id, prod.init_src_sys_id,
>   prod.init_svc_ctr_id, prod.mig_filename)  SELECT stg.application_id,
>   stg.receipt_number, stg.init_frm_id, stg.frm_typ_id, stg.sbmtd_dt_id,
>   stg.crtd_user_id,     stg.init_src_sys_id, stg.init_svc_ctr_id,
>   stg.mig_filename  FROM ecisdrdm.stg_application stg ON CONFLICT
>   (application_id)  DO UPDATE  SET ( prod.init_frm_id,
>   prod.frm_typ_id,prod. sbmtd_dt_id, prod.crtd_user_id, 
>     prod.init_src_sys_id, prod.init_svc_ctr_id, prod.mig_filename,
>   prod.mig_modified_dt )
>   =  (SELECT stg.init_frm_id, stg.frm_typ_id, stg.sbmtd_dt_id, stg.crtd_user_id,    stg.init_src_sys_id, stg.init_svc_ctr_id,
>   stg.mig_filename, current_timestamp FROM ecisdrdm.stg_application_cdim
>   stg WHERE prod.receipt_number = stg.receipt_number );
>   RETURN;
>
> ----    -- Set the return code to 0    ----
>
> v_Ret := SQLCODE;
>
> ---
>
> -- Exception error handler
>   ---- exception    when others then    v_ErrorCode := SQLCODE;     v_ErrorMsg  := SQLERRM;     v_Ret       := v_ErrorCode;
>
> ----    -- Commit the record into the ErrorLog  ----    PERFORM
>   pr_write_error_log( CURRENT_USER, inet_server_addr(), v_Module,
>   v_ErrorCode, v_ErrorMsg );
>
> ----    -- Intentionally leaving the "commit" to application    ---- end;
>   $$ language plpgsql;
>
> ERROR:  function result type must be specified SQL state: 42P13 SELECT
>   ecisdrdm.pr_mig_stg_application_cdim(2000); ERROR:  function
>   ecisdrdm.pr_mig_stg_application_cdim(integer) does not exist LINE 1:
>   SELECT ecisdrdm.pr_mig_stg_application_cdim(2000);
>                  ^
>
> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You
>   might need to add explicit type casts. SQL state: 42883 Character: 8

ERROR:  function pr_mig_stg_application_cdim() does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT pr_mig_stg_application_cdim ();
               ^

> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You
>   might need to add explicit type casts. SQL state: 42883 Character: 8

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?
and how to I run the function as same as Oracle?
DB version 11.1 runs in AWS with pgAdmin v.4.4

Comment: Why did you mess up the formatting I applied?

Comment: I did do anything from your update and I didn't see your updated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58291443/4

Comment: thank you for editing my question.  I already made it work.
v/r,

Comment: If you figured it out, posting the fix as an answer would be great. "Pay Forward" ...

Comment: Making it work has nothing with editing the question, it must be readable and understandable. Questions are for all stackoverflow community :)

Answer (score 0):

working script

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cidrstaging.pr_mig_stg_application_cdim(
    OUT v_ret text)
    RETURNS text
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$
DECLARE 
    v_module                text = 'pr_mig_stg_application_cdim';
    host                    text = inet_server_addr();
    errorcode               text;
    errormsg                text;
    errormsg_detail         text;
    errormsg_hint           text;
        
BEGIN

    ---
    -- Simply delete the data from production table
    ----
    
    DELETE FROM cidrdata.ref_application_cdim WHERE 1=1;

    ---
    --  refresh ref_action_code from stg_ref_action_code
    ---

    INSERT INTO cidrdata.ref_application_cdim
    SELECT stg.code, stg.action, stg.mig_filename
    FROM cidrstaging.stg_ref_application_cdim stg;

    ----
    --   Set return to "Success" for pr_mig_stg_application_cdim function
    ----
    v_ret := 'Success';  

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS 
        errormsg = MESSAGE_TEXT,
        errormsg_detail = PG_EXCEPTION_DETAIL,
        errormsg_hint = PG_EXCEPTION_HINT;  
        errorcode := SQLSTATE;
        v_ret := concat('ERROR - FUNC: ' || v_module || ' ERRORCODE: ', errorcode, ' MSG: ' || errormsg || ' ', errormsg_detail || ' ', errormsg_hint);

    -- NOTE: Only writes to errorlog table if function is called directly
    -- If called through the pr_mig_stg_application_cdim function the exception is raised and caught there instead
    PERFORM cidrstaging.pr_write_error_log( CURRENT_USER, host, v_module, errorcode, v_ret );

END;
$BODY$;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).